# FIleNotFoundError: No such file or Directory Ubuntu Python

Tags: python, ubuntu, operating-system

I am trying to access folders and files of Local Disks in Ubuntu from Python. These are located in **/media/{username}/Local Disk{n}/** where **username** represents the respective username of the pc and **n** represents the local disk number.

When I start my PC and run **os.listdir("/media/hackytech/Local Disk1")** command in terminal I get the **FileNotFoundError** . -- **BUT** When I visit that respective directory graphically[Meaning using keyboard/Mouse] which in case is **Local Disk1** and when I try to run this same command **os.listdir(/media/hackytech/Local Disk1)** I get the results as expected.

I am way too confused, the same path works when it is at least visited one time **graphically[Meaning using keyboard/Mouse]**. BUT when it is not visited and tried to list the directories using **os.listdir()** it throws an Error.

I have attached two images to get clear understanding.

**This is before visiting that respective directory graphically[Meaning using keyboard/Mouse]**
[image]

**This is after visiting those respective directories graphically[Meaning using keyboard/Mouse]**

[image]

Comment: It's not on a network drive that you hadn't yet accessed and therefore couldn't be found before manually navigating to it, is it? Sometimes that happens to me on windows if I try to click straight on a shortcut before clicking on the root directory of a drive

Comment: It is possible that your graphical file manager (nautilus?) mounts the directory when you access it from the GUI, thereby making it available. If it is not mounted os.listdir would not be able to list it. You can confirm this by running the `mount` command before and after accessing the directory from the GUI and comparing the differences.

Comment: @askman yes, I am experience same issue

Comment: @abhijat Makes sense, Thank you so much for your response, will try running `mount`

Comment: This is almost certainly a mount problem as other have suggested. You can isolate Python from the issue by restarting your PC, open terminal window (shell) then try to access it with *ls*

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [abhijat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ox4dp.png) I understood what was the exact issue. The problem is with mounting, when PC is started for first time the OS doesn't mount the Local Disks or any other directories until you visit that directory using GUI.

According to my research, when you visit those Local Disk or any other directory using GUI, by default they are mounted on **/media/{username}/{Directory Name}/** path.

If you want this to mounting to happen automatically while booting PC, follow these following steps

1. First get the UUID(Universally Unique Identifier) of the respective directory which you can do by typing following command in terminal
   `blkid` which will look something like this.
   [image]
2. Then edit the fstab file using `gedit /etc/fstab/` command
3. If we consider doing auto mount for `dev/sdb5/` then this would be the edit for this directory `UUID=DEF68028F67FFED1 /media/hacktech/Local Disk4 ntfs rw,auto,users,exec,nls=utf8,umask=003,gid=46,uid=1000    0   0`
4. Save the file and exit.
5. **The command in 3rd point is different for different file system which are ext4, ext3, nfts etc. So please check for which file system you are applying automounting and use respective command**

This should do the job because it worked for me.
If still didn't understood then visit [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/766854/how-can-an-ext4-partition-automatically-be-mounted-to-var-directory-on-system-s/766866#766866?newreg=87b3ab6aa73241849e481a299f4d0d92)

**PLEASE INFORM ME IF THE ABOVE INFORMATION IF WRONG I WILL DELETE THIS ANSWER IMMEDIATELY, I DON'T HAVE COMPLETE KNOWLEDGE OF HOW UBUNTU WORKS, BUT AFTER SOME OF RESEARCH THIS IS WHAT I HAVE LEARNED**